# tree plotted by ctree has no splits

Tags: machine-learning

I've computed a ctree model, but the individual tree plotted is just one level, with all samples (below). How could this scenario have occurred? My response variable is a principal component and the predictors are nine environmental variables. There is no problem when I compute other principal components for the same dataset, so it's not the environmental variables.[image: ctree model with no splits]

Comment: P.s - I tried all combinations of minsplit and minbucket. Criterion was set at 0.95, and varied to 0.90.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.